# ¿Como validar datos a traves de funciones?

Tags: javascript

tengo este programa que recoge datos de peliculas los almacena en un array y despues muestra por pantalla su titulo,el problema viene que quiero validar los datos des otra funcion, osea quiero que no se puedan repetir los nombres de las peliculas ya guardadas en el array solo que en lugar de ponerlo en una funcion lo hago en dos funciones distintas pero no consigo hacer que me funcione correctamente. Dicho esto aqui dejo el codigo.

javascript:

```
var filmoteca = new Array();

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = insertar;
}
function peliculas(titulo, director, anyo, descripcion) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.director = director;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

function insertar() {
    var numpelis = parseInt(prompt("Cuantas pelis vas a insertar"));
    for (let i = 0; i < numpelis; i++) {
        var creacion = insertarpeliculas();
        peliculas.push(creacion);
    }
}

function insertarpeliculas() {
    
        var titulo = prompt("Insertar el nombre de la pelicula");

        filmoteca.forEach(element => {
           if(element.titulo == titulo){
            comprobarnombre();
           }
        });

        var director = prompt("Inserta nombre de director");
        var year = parseInt(prompt("Inserta el año de la pelicula"));
        var descripcion = prompt("Insertar sinopsis de la pelicula");
    
        var filmoteca = new cartelera(titulo,director,year,descripcion);
        return filmoteca;
}

function comprobarnombre(titulo) {
    var comprobar;
    do {
        comprobar = true;
       
        filmoteca.forEach(element => {
           if(element.titulo == titulo){
            alert("Titulo repetido");
            comprobar = false;
           }
        });
    } while (comprobar == false);
}

filmoteca.forEach(element => {
    document.write(element.titulo +  " <br>");
    document.write(element.director);
});
```

html:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="insertar">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo muchas inconsistencias en el código, acá te dejo el Script de como se podría manejar:

```
var filmoteca = new Array();

  window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = insertar;
  };

  function cartelera(titulo, director, anyo, descripcion) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.director = director;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
  }

  function insertar() {
    var numpelis = parseInt(prompt('Cuantas pelis vas a insertar'));
    for (let i = 0; i < numpelis; i++) {
      var creacion = insertarpeliculas();
      filmoteca.push(creacion);
    }
    filmoteca.forEach((element) => {
      document.write(element.titulo + ' <br>');
      document.write(element.director);
    });
  }

  function insertarpeliculas() {
    var titulo = prompt('Insertar el nombre de la pelicula');

    // Comprobar que el nombre no se repita
    titulo = comprobarnombre(titulo);

    var director = prompt('Inserta nombre de director');
    var year = parseInt(prompt('Inserta el año de la pelicula'));
    var descripcion = prompt('Insertar sinopsis de la pelicula');

    return new cartelera(titulo, director, year, descripcion);
  }

  function comprobarnombre(titulo) {
    let repetida;
    do {
      repetida = filmoteca.some((element) => {
        return element.titulo === titulo;
      });
      if (repetida) {
        alert('Titulo repetido');
        titulo = prompt('Insertar el nombre de la pelicula');
      }
    } while (repetida);
    return titulo;
  }
```

Comment: Sería bueno que expliques los cambios realizados y cómo funcionan o mejoran el código original.

Comment: Muchas gracias, a todo esto la funcion co mprobar nombre podria utilizarla para crear comprobaciones de los otro campos de insertar peliculas o debo crear funciones distintas

Comment: @Jos: Si esta respuesta responde correctamente a tu pregunta inicial márcala como Aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente de responder eternamente.  Si tienes nuevas preguntas que realizar sírvete hacerlas creándolas como nuevas.